# How do I get the Segmented Control index from one view controller to another containerview controller in Swift iOS development?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am using the three index segmented control in one of the view controller naming as dashboard controller and passing the segue to container view to load the three different view controllers in the dashboard controller still the selected index is showing the segmented control but container view loading the default first view controllers under dashboard controller.

Comment: Can you please show some code?

Answer (score 0):

You can go through with this link and it will help you with your problem.

> http://codingdiscovery.blogspot.com/2015/03/swap-viewcontrollers-with-segmented.html

[![And fill in the functionality of the value changed method to hide/show the blue container based on the segment index:
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4hT4.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4hT4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it.

- Don't link the segmented control to a segue directly, but **to an action in the dashboard controller**.
- Swap out the views from the dashboard controller.

---

```
func switchViews(_ sender: Any?) {
    // vcSelector is an instance variable, or you can use the sender
    let subVCIndex = vcSelector?.selectedSegmentIndex
    // also an instance variable
    currentViewController = nil
    switch subVCIndex {
        case 0:
            currentViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SubControllerA")
            // set up for case 0
        case 1:
            currentViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SubControllerB")
            // set up for case 1
        // ...
        default:
            // should never happen
            NSLog("*** Invalid view mode! ***")
            return // bail out
    }

    // add the new view controller
    self.addChildViewController(currentViewController!)

    // take out all the old subviews
    for subview in self.containerView!.subviews {
        subview.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    // install the new subVC's view
    self.containerView?.addSubview(currentViewController!.view)
    currentViewController!.view.frame = self.containerView!.bounds
}
```